# How to connect MySql database with Firebase?

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to connect MySql database with Firebase. This is for real time data updates and show it on browser. Already created Firebase account and got config code. Now I want connect my existing MySql based database with Firebase.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: what will you after connecting ?

Comment: Basically I developed php web application and using MySql database. In some of the pages I need to show some realtime data. So. I'm trying firebase to achieve this.

Answer (score 12):

This is something that I have been interested in recently as well.

Here is a great article that should answer your question:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html

"Pattern 2: Firebase-powered app with server code" can probably provide you with a solution to connect Firebase to your MySQL DB.

What you could do is have your PHP app send updates to your firebase db when ever something update-worthy happens in your MySQL database. If all your clients are then subscribing/watching the changes to your Firebase db, then you have (albeit  indirectly) connected your MySQL database with your Firebase db.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you have a cron job to watch firebase db?  or use firebase messaging?

Comment: @Thufir Hey Thufir, your php server code would subscribe to the firebase db similarly to how other clients do. In that way, your php server would be notified of firebase updates just like it would if it were a browser client.

Answer (score 2):

You can store and retrieve Firebase data using REST API. Create the API in the same server as the Mysql database  - this will work from any environment that lets you make HTTPS requests.