# Is there any "firebase for MySQL"?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, database

I am currently working on a Database project for the university and I need to create a web app that communicates to a MySQL database.

Since the focus of the project is the actual MySQL and not the server-side stuff(PHP, node.js), is there anything like firebase for MySQL where I can make API calls from the frontend(js) to the database with custom SQL queries and not have to develop (or develop the minimum) server code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696408/how-to-connect-mysql-database-with-firebase.

Comment: Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSDHdWrSqLY&list=PLvGm4ZwQQE68ZQ5TrvAYyGI9zi83jf2BB&index=2&t=0s

Comment: Neither of those links answer your actual question, IMO. I believe you were asking if MySQL had a web API equivalent to firebase's, rather than how to link MySQL and Firebase together. The short answer is "no", mySQL does not have that. You need to write something in server-side code which will interact with the database.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson that was the answer I was looking for.